# git fork master always ahead of origin/master, on local and remote

Tags: git, github, git-fork

Both my local repository and my fork are always ahead of origin/master. I'm currently just pushing to my master without making a separate branch. This is my workflow, which is the same workflow I've always used for other projects, without issue:

```
git pull origin master
```

make changes to code

```
git commit -m "made change"
git push remote master
```

where remote is my personal fork. Then I submit a pull request to origin/master from github, which always gets merged without issue.

Using this workflow, somehow my local repository is always ahead by all commits I've made to the repo. Even after my pull requests are merged into origin/master, both my fork on github and my local repo say that they are x commits ahead of origin/master (even though the commits show up in the commit history of origin master). Another annoying side effect of this is that every time I pull from origin master, I have to do a merge commit because my local repo thinks it's ahead.

Does anyone know what could be going on? I've always used this workflow, but I've never encountered these problems before.

Comment: Are they squashing or rebasing the commits when they accept the pull request?

Comment: How can I tell?

Comment: You can take a look at the pull request and see how it ended up, and then take a look at the root repository and find your changes/commits and see how that looks.

Comment: “Even after my pull requests are merged into origin/master” When does that happen? You never pushed anything to origin. Please show your real workflow.

Comment: I have a sentence after this explaining that I then submit a pull request to origin/master

Comment: Lasse, I don't see anything out of the ordinary when looking at the closed pull request, or my commits. Can you give me more specifics on what I should be looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maintainers of the upstream repository are probably using the "rebase and merge" button on GitHub.  This *copies* your commits to new (and supposedly improved, but perhaps not actually improved at all—perhaps just *different*) commits in *their* repository.  The copied commits have different hash IDs and therefore are different commits.

The end result of this action is that they will be ahead of your branch by N commits *and* you will be ahead of *their* branch by the same N commits.  (N here is the number of commits that were in your pull request.)  That's just a simple matter of counting, after all: when you started the pull request, you had:

```
...--o--o--*   <-- their-branch
            \
             1--2--3   <-- your-branch
```

in your repository, where the numbered commits are your new ones.  They then *copied* those commits so that once you obtain them, you have:

```
...--o--o--*--A--B--C   <-- their-branch
            \
             1--2--3   <-- your-branch
```

where `A-B-C` are their copies of your `1-2-3`.  Since `*` is the last commit that's on *both* branches, they are now ahead 3, while you are also ahead 3.

You can tell that this has happened by obtaining any commits from them, into a real, actual, *local* Git repository (not some distant GitHub one where you have to guess at things) and inspecting the commit hash IDs and commits.  If your commits have been copied to new ones, the hash IDs will not match, even if everything else about the commits *does* match.

If this is the case, they expect you to, like them, throw out *your* commits in favor of their new and (supposedly) improved commits.  You can choose whether to do this or not.  If you choose not to do it, you make your future work more difficult for yourself.  If you choose to do it, you make your current work more difficult for yourself (though this may be a very low / small level of difficulty).  That's your choice, which is forced upon you because they used "rebase and merge".

Comment: Beautifully written and well explained. Can you tell me how to throw out my commits in favor of theirs?

Comment: There are multiple ways, some easier than others. For instance, you can: `git checkout your-branch; git rebase their-branch` and if the commits are patch-equivalent, your `git rebase` will toss them while keeping others. If you have no other commits, just delete your branch and make a new one that starts from their branch-tip. Either way, anyone *else* who's using *your* commits to build more commits must do something too—basically the same thing you have to do.

Comment: If they made any substantive changes to your commits, you may have to use `git rebase -i` and explicitly drop your own commits. Before you do that, make sure you *like* their commits that are substantively different from yours!